Matplotlib not rendering TeX symbol "as promised"
I have the following TeX expression in one of my Matplotlib plots:
\sum_{n=1}^\infty

And it renders this:

However, Matplotlib, in its manual, says it would render something like this:

The positions of the n = 1 and of the infinity symbol are not below and above the summation symbol - they are slightly to the right. This is ugly and inefficient as it takes more writing space than it should.
The sigma symbol itself is aesthetically nicer in the manual than it actually appears in my plot. I tried several combinations of font families, fonts, styles, etc, to no avail. Matplotlib is such an awesome package - its downside is its complexity when it comes to those "fine details". I can't figure out how those rc, rcParams, etc, work exactly. I use them based on examples I find in Google or other pages such as Matplotlib's manual.
Any hints? I'm using Windows 11, Python 3.10.8, Matplotlib 3.9.2.

If you add a \displaystyle before your expression does it work?

@RoySmart It does!!! Thanks!

@RoySmart And if I place the \displaystyle in front of the whole expression the final result gets a lot nicer!
